# knockoutjs when checked data binding call function

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I need to do following things: When user checks the checkbox, some function is called.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="what to write here?" />
```

and in model:

```
var viewModel = {
    this.someFunction = function() {
       console.log("1");
    }
};
```

I have not found anything about this is documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you need is the [`click` binding:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: someFunction" />
```

And in your view model:

```
var ViewModel = function(data, event) {
    this.someFunction = function() {
       console.log(event.target.checked); // log out the current state
       console.log("1");
       return true; // to trigger the browser default behavior  
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GH2tJ/1/)

Or if you want to you use the `checked` binding you can subscribe on the change event of your property:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />
```

And in your viewmodel:

```
var ViewModel = function() {

    this.isChecked = ko.observable();

    this.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue){
        this.someFunction(newValue);
    }, this);

    this.someFunction = function(value) {
        console.log(value); // log out the current state
        console.log("1");
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qx8DC/1/)

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish when checkbox is selected and when unselected?

Comment: When using the `subscribe` you get the value with: `this.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue){` see http://jsfiddle.net/qx8DC/1/ and in the click binding case you can get with  `this.someFunction = function(data,event) {
        console.log(event.target.checked);` see: http://jsfiddle.net/GH2tJ/1/